# Why does my css menu have text overlapping on drop down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I can't  get my drop down menu (sub-menu) to stop overlapping the text. Below is my HTML + CSS.

```
<ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" >Events </a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="index-1.html">Store</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index-2.html" >Imagination CD</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-2.html" >Total Relax</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-2.html" >Super Study</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </li>   
    </li>
    <li><a href="index-2.html" class="active">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="index-3.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.top-menu {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 32px 00 0 10px;
    height: 85px;
}
.top-menu li{
    padding:0 24px 0 0;
}
.top-menu li, .top-menu li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.top-menu ul, .top-menu ul a{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index:999px;
    line-height: 30px;
    top: 12px;
}
.top-menu li a{
    padding:0 0 0 30px;
    color:#4d3925;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.top-menu a:hover, .top-menu .active {
    color:#f29869;
}
.top-menu li:hover ul a,  .top-menu li:hover ul {
    position: abolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 32px 0 0 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    z-index: 999px;
}
```

reference menu: http://www.nicoheins.com/lux/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this dropdown. However, the one that's causing this particular problem is the attribute `position:absolute;` in your selector `.top-menu ul, .top-menu ul a`. Once you get rid of that, your links will no longer stack on top of eachother.

But you'll still need to do more work to get your menu looking fresh.

Not to plug my own work, but I've got a pretty decent dropdown (I think, at least) that you can use hosted over at Github. [Check it out here](https://github.com/jmeas/CSS3-Dropdown-With-Fade). If you don't want the fade or arrows, you can just remove those, then apply your own style. The rest should work as you want it to.

Edits to fix other issues:

Again, the original question just asks to solve one of the problems I noted with this dropdown. Another is the fact that your submenu `ul` is pushing the parents `li`s to the right. You can fix this by applying this styling:

```
.top-menu > li {
    position: relative;
}
.top-menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Another is the fact that your all of your `li`s are styled to `float:left;`. You only want the top level `li`s to be styled in this way. This is cased by this section:

```
.top-menu li, .top-menu li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Changing this to

```
.top-menu > li, .top-menu > li > a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

will fix that, but then you'll need to re-apply the `display:block;` to the submenu `a`s.

I imagine your next concern would be regarding the *huge* spacing between the submenu `a`s. This is because you're targeting them with this code:

```
.top-menu li:hover ul a,  .top-menu li:hover ul {
    position: abolute;
    display: block;
    padding: 32px 0 0 14px;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 999px;
}
```

That `padding-top` is quite large! Be sure your selectors are *only* selecting what you want, or you'll end up getting strange behavior like this. This is particular important when you're working with something like a dropdown, which has `li`s inside of `li`s, and they need to be styled completely different from one another.

For a good overview of selectors, [check out this page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

A functional version of this is [here](http://jmeas.com/projects/so/lit/). Please note that I tried to change the original `css` as little as possible. I think this has restricted my ability to write the best possible dropdown that I think I can write. But this does work!

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amK3c/) with rewritten code that works completely and cleanly!.

Comment: Hi jmeas, Thank you for replying. when I take out the position: absolute, everything moves to the side of the menu :( . Any further suggestions? I really want to keep the code I have, and tweak it.

Comment: Hey man, I'll fix it up for you and post the code. Give me a minute.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it up just a bit more for you. It's almost there; maybe you'll be able to take it from here? But if you need more help, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but you're a smart guy. could you post the CSS in its entirety?

Comment: hmmm, the padding-top is to center it on the div.... Jmeas, I tried what you commented, and I truly appreciate it, but it will not work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: Hey man, I'm trying to put together something that looks nice for you. It's tough because you wanted to keep the code as intact as possible, so I'm not trying to change your selectors much. It's just that you've got way more things in here than you need. You can achieve this with just 3 selectors! Anyway, stay tuned. I'll post you something in a minute.

Comment: Okay. Here you go; a *functioning* dropdown. [Click here.](http://jmeas.com/projects/so/lit/) I can only say functioning because there's a lot of room for improvement. If you take a look at the Git I linked, you can see that I separate out the style of the menu from its functionality. Essentially only 3 selectors are responsible for all the neat hover action. Anyway, keep asking for help if you need it.

Comment: you da man! I am going to implement this tomorrow when I'm awake :) Have a great night, i'll let you know if i stumble into anything else...

Comment: Hi Jmeas! so strange, never had such a hard time with a menu before. Now the submenu dissapears under the nav bar, and I had to put the top padding back to 32px because otherwise it wasn't centered along the menu bar.... help!

Comment: It's hard for me to visualize what you're referring to. Can you upload it so I can see?

Also, it's kind of tough working with the CSS you have right now. If you show me a picture of exactly what you want, I can write up clearer CSS for you that'll be easier for you to modify.

Comment: I'll send you a box of chocolates when you get it working! The following image is what it looks like in my browser[link]http://www.rejournals.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-shot-2012-10-11-at-10.15.08-AM.png[link]

Edit: I am open to having you create it however you want, but I think it has something to do with the Z-index. it would probably help if you downloaded the files.... Let me know, you are a life saver!

Comment: link didn't work... 

http://www.rejournals.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-shot-2012-10-11-at-10.15.08-AM.png

I am looking for something functional and simple.

Comment: Cool man, thanks for giving me the link. I'm headed off to class so I won't be able to look at this for a few hours. I'll set it up later this evening :)

Comment: awesome, hopefully class was eventful. Can't wait to see what you tweak. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amK3c/). I lost the original HTML so I did some of the styling off memory, but yeah...it should be easy to style and adjust that according to what you want. If you put the webpage back up, I can implement it there myself and hand you the code back.

Comment: You are a genius, has anyone told you that? JSFiddle looks slick. I just put the site back up; I tried implementing it but I must be CSS challenged... I want to reward you for all your hard work... Could you implement and spit back the code to me?

Comment: Hey, I tried doing this and it *should* be working, but for some reason the `absolute` positioning on the submenu is positioning the *entire* menu with respect to the window, rather than just the parent element. It's kind of tough debugging it (the `css`/`html` is a bit of a mess, to be honest), but I'll keep toying with it this weekend...

Comment: Ah Jmeas, thank you for helping out. I have been trying as well, to no avail.  What shoudl I do? :\ Is there another way we can do it? Cheers mate.

Comment: have you had any luck Jmeas? I'm counting on ya, and I will reward you for it... =)